# Ошибка в JSON

Tags: json, javascript

Почему так?

> > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '15' of undefined

**Код:**

```
var list_json = '[{"beeline": {"15": "17"}}, {"megafon": {"15": "20"}}]';
var list_json_parse = JSON.parse(list_json);
alert(list_json_parse['beeline']['15']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка валидна. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) не показывает никакой ошибки. Chrome тоже:

```
JSON.parse('[{"beeline": {"15": "17"}}, {"megafon": {"15": "20"}}]');
>> [Object, Object]
```

UPD: потому-что у вас `list_json_parse` - это массив объектов. И надо сначала обратиться к элементу массива, а потом уже к свойствам объекта:

```
list_json_parse[0]['beeline']['15']
>> "17"
```

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, обновил пост. Вот как сейчас не работает.

Comment: @ModaL, обновил ответ.